# Replacing space in url with code

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have this code.

Which I have set up to promote the page on my site.

```
<script ... > 
document.write('<a href="mailto:?subject=my%20subject&body='+top.location.href+'">mail this link to a friend</a>'); 
</script>
```

However in my url it has a space on most of my campaigns. This breaks up the url in my promotional email so the `http://` up to the first space is hyperlinked.

How do I replace the space in my url for the space code in the code above meaning that the whole link will be hyperlinked in the email?

Comment: You want to replace the spaces in `top.location.href` ? Simple as this: `top.location.href.replace(/\s/g, '%20')`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write('<a href="mailto:?subject=my%20subject&body=' + encodeURIComponent(top.location.href) + '">mail this link to a friend</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode url first, eg. using `encodeURIComponent` function.

```
encodeURIComponent(top.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script ... > 
var url2 = encodeURIComponent(top.location.href);

document.write('<a href="mailto:?subject=my%20subject&body='+url2 +'">mail this link to a      friend</a>');
```